# Bootstrap the standard error of the mean using purrr::rerun() in R

Tags: r, purrr, statistics-bootstrap

I'm trying to bootstrap the standard error of the mean using the `purrr::rerun()` function in R. For example, here I'm trying to find the bootsrapped standard error for the **Sepal.Length** variable

```
sample_the_mean <- function(x) {
    the_sample <- sample(x, replace = TRUE)
    mean(the_sample)
}

sample_the_mean(iris$Sepal.Length)

#> [1] 5.894667
```

Seemed to work fine when used one time. Here's with `purrr::rerun()`; I'll just show the first list element of the output (but the list has an element for every iteration, so 10 total elements):

```
    out <- purrr::rerun(10, sample_the_mean, x = iris$Sepal.Length)

    out[[1]]

#> [[1]]
#> function (x) 
#> {
#>     the_sample <- sample(x, replace = TRUE)
#>     mean(the_sample)
#> }
#> 
#> $x
#>   [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.6 5.0 4.4 4.9 5.4 4.8 4.8 4.3 5.8 5.7 5.4
#>  [18] 5.1 5.7 5.1 5.4 5.1 4.6 5.1 4.8 5.0 5.0 5.2 5.2 4.7 4.8 5.4 5.2 5.5
#>  [35] 4.9 5.0 5.5 4.9 4.4 5.1 5.0 4.5 4.4 5.0 5.1 4.8 5.1 4.6 5.3 5.0 7.0
#>  [52] 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 5.7 6.3 4.9 6.6 5.2 5.0 5.9 6.0 6.1 5.6 6.7 5.6 5.8
#>  [69] 6.2 5.6 5.9 6.1 6.3 6.1 6.4 6.6 6.8 6.7 6.0 5.7 5.5 5.5 5.8 6.0 5.4
#>  [86] 6.0 6.7 6.3 5.6 5.5 5.5 6.1 5.8 5.0 5.6 5.7 5.7 6.2 5.1 5.7 6.3 5.8
#> [103] 7.1 6.3 6.5 7.6 4.9 7.3 6.7 7.2 6.5 6.4 6.8 5.7 5.8 6.4 6.5 7.7 7.7
#> [120] 6.0 6.9 5.6 7.7 6.3 6.7 7.2 6.2 6.1 6.4 7.2 7.4 7.9 6.4 6.3 6.1 7.7
#> [137] 6.3 6.4 6.0 6.9 6.7 6.9 5.8 6.8 6.7 6.7 6.3 6.5 6.2 5.9
```

As you can see, not the mean, but rather the sample itself is returned. Any thoughts on why this is? How can I do this differently? I'd prefer to not use a package (other than **purrr**, in this particular case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
set.seed(2018)
purrr::rerun(10, sample_the_mean(iris$Sepal.Length))
 #[[1]]
#[1] 5.73
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 5.810667
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 5.868667
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 5.902
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 5.844
#
#[[6]]
#[1] 5.746667
#
#[[7]]
#[1] 5.877333
#
#[[8]]
#[1] 5.853333
#
#[[9]]
#[1] 5.821333
#
#[[10]]
#[1] 5.768
```

You can see from `?rerun` that `...` refers to the expressions to be re-run. So in your case you need to specify a single expression as `sample_the_mean(iris$Sepal.Length)`, which will get captured as a quosure and then evaluated. Perhaps type `rerun` into an R terminal to see what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Am I wrong to think that this behaves a bit differently than other **purrr** functions (i.e., `map()`)?

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg Yes, `map` behaves similarly to `lapply`, while `rerun` behaves similar to base R's `replicate`.

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg If this answers your question, please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer.